# ReactJS: How can I programmatically redirect a user to another page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have a basic ReactJS 4.0.1 app set up with routes using react-router-dom 5.0.1.

I also have a middleware that checks if the user's session time has expired. From there, I want to simply redirect the user to the sign in page.

I literally just want to change pages. If this was in .net, I would just call:

`return RedirectToAction("Index", model);`

Very simple.

Previously, to change content in different components, I had an if statement in the render section that would redirect by returning:

`<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/signin' }}/>`

to the user. This worked if the user took the action that triggered code within the component, but the logic I'm handling is in middleware.

I've tried
history.push, goto, location.push, store.push, etc...
I can't get any of that to work.
From my middleware, I have access to the Store from redux.  What can I do with that?

Answer (score 2):

You can with `history` object. Just export `history` object and call `history.push('some-page')`. I made a demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-fire-1vihp

`export const history = createBrowserHistory()`

and pass history props to Router

`<Router history={history}>`

in middleware file just call `history.push('some-page')`.

Another way is use library like `react-router-redux`,